# Preg_match return array of positions of each match with PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE

Tags: php, function, preg-match

Having trouble returning an array of positions:

```
function returnPosition($string,$start){ 
     preg_match('/' . preg_quote($start, '/').'/im', $string, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    $startArr = array();

    foreach ($m as $value)
    {
        $startArr = array_push($startArr, $m);
    }
    //var_dump($startArr);
    return $startArr;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: -1? I just spent a significant amount of time trying different methods to return an array of position values...

Answer (score 2):

No surprise, you're [using array_push wrong](http://php.net/array_push). It does **NOT** return the modified array. It returns the new number of elements in the array, so on each iteration you're trashing what used to be an array with an int. Try

```
$startArr[] = $m;
```

or at least just

```
array_push($startArr, $m);
```

with no assignment at all.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, I'm getting `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "hello" [1]=> int(0) } } }` in a var_dump. It looks like the arrays are nested using input `returnPosition("hello there hello hello","hello");`. Also I only need the position number, so how would I end up with an array like this(1, 13, 20)?

Comment: http://php.net/preg_match_all  read the note about `preg_offset_capture`. same thing holds for preg_match.

Comment: thanks, checked that out and tried re-purposing some of the examples (which usually works for me), but it is still not clear to me. As simple as it seems, I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now...

Comment: `$startArr[] = $m[1]` would push only the offset value.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, however I get an undefined offset error when using `$startArr[] = $m[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works for me:

```
function getTagPositions($strBody, $start, $end)
{
    preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([\w\s.]*?)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/im', $strBody, $strTag, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $intOffset = 0;
    $intIndex = 0;
    $intTagPositions = array();

    foreach($strTag[0] as $strFullTag) {
        $intTagPositions[$intIndex] = array('start' => (strpos($strBody, $strFullTag, $intOffset)), 'end' => (strpos($strBody, $strFullTag, $intOffset) + strlen($strFullTag)));
        $intOffset += strlen($strFullTag);
        $intIndex++;
    }
    return $intTagPositions;
}


$intTagPositions = getTagPositions("hello there hello hello","he","lo");
// returns
Array ( [0] => Array ( [start] => 0 [end] => 5 ) [1] => Array ( [start] => 7 [end] => 17 ) [2] => Array ( [start] => 18 [end] => 23 ) )
```